# kube-flannel-rbac.yml - 404 error (not able to install)

Tags: kubernetes, installation, http-status-code-404, flannel

I am trying to run this command -
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-rbac.yml

but it gives following output

solve error - "error: unable to read URL "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/coreos/flannel/master/Documentation/kube-flannel-rbac.yml", server reported 404 Not Found, status code=404"

I am running this on ubuntu on AWS ec2.

Answer (score 2):

You got a 404 simply because that file does not exist anymore on `master` branch.

You can find the `kube-flannel-rbac.yaml` in the `k8s-old-manifests` folder: https://github.com/flannel-io/flannel/blob/v0.22.2/Documentation/k8s-old-manifests/kube-flannel-rbac.yml.

To install it (version `v0.22.2`), you can:

```bash
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flannel-io/flannel/v0.22.2/Documentation/k8s-old-manifests/kube-flannel-rbac.yml
```

Note that this `kube-flannel-rbac.yaml` has disappeared since version `v0.20.0`. This is why you can't find it on `master` branch, that you're trying to reach. You can find it in older versions, like `v0.19.0`:

```bash
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/flannel-io/flannel/v0.19.0/Documentation/k8s-manifests/kube-flannel-rbac.yml
```

BTW:

- `coreos/flannel` has been moved to `flannel-io/flannel` (but I guess you can still use `coreos/flannel` in the URL as it will redirect you automatically)
- be careful to use the manifest corresponding to the Flannel version you're trying to install to avoid surprises